# R transparent planes3d should not hide plot3d points/spheres

Tags: r, 3d, transparency, rgl

I want to put points/spheres and a plane in one 3d-plot. I would like the plane to be have an alpha-transparency of ~0.5 (it should neither be completely transparent nor completely opaque). So that I can see the points/spheres and the axis through the plane.

I tried:

```
library(rgl)

#Generating points:
m=20
a1=runif(m,-1,1)
a2=runif(m,-1,1)
b=a1+2*a2+rnorm(m,mean=0,sd=0.3)

# Plotting the points:
plot3d(a1,a2,b, type='s', xlim = c(-1, 1), ylim = c(-1, 1), zlim = c(-3.1, 3.1),xlab = 'a_i,1', ylab = 'a_i,2', zlab = 'b_i',alpha=0.9)
# Plotting the transparent plane:
planes3d(1, 2, -1, 0, col = 'red', alpha = 0.1, add=T)
# plot the points again (because I thought, maybe the the execution order could be relevant)
plot3d(a1,a2,b, add=T, type='s', xlim = c(-1, 1), ylim = c(-1, 1), zlim = c(-3.1, 3.1),xlab = 'a_i,1', ylab = 'a_i,2', zlab = 'b_i',alpha=0.9)
```

The result that I get is that I can see the axis through the plane, but I cannot see the points/spheres that hide behind the plane :(

parts of the spheres can't be seen through the plane:
[image]

I wish to see also the points/spheres through the plane (like it works so well for the axis, that can seen through the plane).
I want to see all 20 points / spehres, also those that are covered / hidden / concealed / masked by the plane.

Comment: You code is incomplete. plot3d is in `rgl` not `scatterplot3d`. Your call to `planes3d` uses the variable x but no x has been defined.

Comment: @ulfelder Thank you, but I think alpha is a graphical parameter used by `planes3D`, because it works well for the axis and in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30960620/how-to-plot-a-plane-from-an-equation-in-r) it works well for multiple planes (one can see every plane through all the other planes)

Comment: @Jakob Thanks for updating your code.  As it is,  it works for me just fine. I get a transparent plane and see the points through the plane. If you have not already done so,  I suggest restarting R and running the code above exactly as it is. It is working for me.

Comment: @G5W Thanks, when I tried this, I recognized that I forgot the line `m=20` so I added this line. But after restarting R, I still could not see the spheres through the plane. I can only see the parts of the spheres, that are not covered by the plane :(

Comment: I see the same problem as Jakob.  Looks like a bug to me:  the plane is writing to the z buffer, but since it is partially transparent, it shouldn't.

Comment: It is possible that if your webgl is using hardware acceleration, and the hardware accelerated GL library can handle multiple layer transparency (I imagine some of them can) it will render it correctly. But mine certainly does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using "data oriented routines", which render quickly, but distort the axes since the data points typically do not relate to each other geometrically. Probably it is clipping and rendering for speed and ignoring alpha buffers in order to rapidly be able to plot a lot of points.

If you use a different rendering technique you can get this, but it is a lot slower of course. And it respects the aspect ratio between the coordinates.

```
library(rgl)

sphere3d <- function(cen, r=1,n = 65, ...){
  f <- function(s,t){ 
    cbind(   r * cos(t)*cos(s) + cen[1],
             r *        sin(s) + cen[2],
             r * sin(t)*cos(s) + cen[3])
  }
  persp3d(f, slim = c(-pi/2,pi/2), tlim = c(0, 2*pi), n = n, add = T,axes=T,...)
}

m=20
xx=runif(m,-1,1)
yy=runif(m,-1,1)
zz=xx+2*yy+rnorm(m,mean=0,sd=0.3)

# Plotting the points:
for (i in 1:m){
  cen <- c(xx[i],yy[i],zz[i])
  sphere3d(cen,col="black",r=0.15,n=17)
}

# add corner points to make the bounding box span the space
sphere3d(c(-1,-1,-3),col="black",r=0.15,n=17)
sphere3d(c( 1, 1, 3),col="black",r=0.15,n=17)

# Plotting the transparent plane:
planes3d(1, 2, -1, 0, col = 'red', alpha = 0.5)

# no axes by default
axes3d( edges="bbox",box=T )
```

Yielding this - however note that it is also not perfect - and screws up in a similar way when you set transparency on the spheres as well. In general you can only do multiple layer transparency completely correctly with something ray tracing related which is terribly slow:

[image]

Here is another view head-on with alpha set to 0.8.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!!! The alpha-value for the spheres doesn't have an high priority to me. Your code is fast enough for my application and the pictures I get with your code look great :)

Comment: OK, but please accept the answer, and upvote it when you get enough points :)

Comment: I have already upvoted you, but StackOverflow will only count it, after I got reputation>=15.

If someone has an Idea how to improve your solution, I would appreciate this too.

Comment: Maybe the other guy will fix the bug :)

Comment: He did.  Try rgl 0.98.4 from R-forge (or from Github when it eventually catches up, or CRAN in a few weeks).

Answer (score 3):

I think it's a bug, but there's a workaround.  When you plot the plane, say explicitly that you don't want depth masking, i.e. use

```
planes3d(1, 2, -1, 0, col = 'red', alpha = 0.1, depth_mask = FALSE)
```

Edited to add:

There are really two bugs.  The line above fixes one.  The other bug is that the plane is drawn before the spheres, because it is not clipped by the `xlim`, `ylim`, `zlim` values like the spheres are.  (This is unavoidable if they are both transparent, but if the spheres are solid, they should be drawn first.)  You can force it to be drawn second with another workaround.  After the `plot3d()` call, run the following:

```
subs <- subsceneInfo()
useSubscene3d(subs$children)
planes3d(1, 2, -1, 0, col = 'red', alpha = 0.1, depth_mask = FALSE)
useSubscene3d(subs$id)
```

Or if the limits aren't important, just leave them out, and things will just work without any other workaround.

Comment: Except that make it look like all the spheres are in front. Not sure that would help much.

Comment: If the spheres have alpha=1, they'll obscure the plane where they are in front of it, but the plane will draw over the part of the sphere that's behind, so it should be fine.   Jakob set alpha to 0.9, which makes things harder.  Then rgl tries to draw from back to front, but it doesn't always get it right (because some polygons intersect, so it isn't well defined which one is in front).

Comment: Sorry, Mike is right -- the bug is different than I thought.

Comment: @user2554330 Thanks, but like you corrected yourself even when I don't set an alpha-value for the spheres, like: `# Plotting the points:
plot3d(a1,a2,b, type='s', xlim = c(-1, 1), ylim = c(-1, 1), zlim = c(-3.1, 3.1),xlab = 'a_i,1', ylab = 'a_i,2', zlab = 'b_i')
# Plotting the transparent plane:
planes3d(1, 2, -1, 0, col = 'red', alpha = 0.9, add=T,depth_mask = FALSE)` results in all spheres looking like they are in front.